# Build single executable with Install Shield automation tool 2009

Tags: installation, installshield, packaging

I am trying to automate the packaging process and stop using the GUI using install shield 2009 automation tool.

I have an Install Script Project and seems that there is no Build function in the automation tool that will allow me to Build a single executable image as the GUI has . I have searched to the manual and there is no Build function for Install Script projects.

Is it possible to build this kind of project with the install shield 2009 automation tool?

Thank you in advance

Comment: After you change or create your project with the VBscript.You are running the script with the usage of the ISCmdBuild.exe that is located inside the /programFiles/installShield/System in your computer.With specific flags you say where you want to place your executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change or create your project with the VBscript.You are running the script with the usage of the ISCmdBuild.exe that is located inside the /programFiles/installShield/System in your computer.
With specific flags you say where you want to place your executable.

Answer (score 1):

If your project type is InstallScript，you need ISCmdBuild.exe and ReleasePackager.exe to build a self-extracting executable file from the command line.